# Flask app packaged with PyInstaller with no templates nor static included in EXE

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I´m trying to pack my `run.py` app into `run.exe`, but not including html `templates` and the `static` folder files in the .exe file, so they can be easily changed and updated without the need to recompile the .exe file.

The app structure is:

```
 run.py
   /serversystem
      /templates
      /static
      /main
      /users
```

In "main" and "users" folders there are empty `__init__.py` files, and `routes.py` files with the actual code, in a Blueprint architecture.

I am using `pyinstaller --onefile run.py` and copying the packaged `dist\run.exe` file to the root folder where `run.py` lives.

The error I get is that Jinja cannot find the template when I tell it to render it. This is from `http://localhost:3000/about`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\serversystem\main\routes.py", line 17, in about
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\templating.py", line 148, in render_template
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\jinja2\environment.py", line 1068, in get_or_select_template
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\jinja2\environment.py", line 997, in get_template
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\jinja2\environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\templating.py", line 59, in get_source
    
  File "C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171402\flask\templating.py", line 95, in _get_source_fast
    
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: about.html
```

The same code works well in the IDE.

I have added a chunk of code to `/systemserver/__init__.py` that goes:

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
 if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
     print("Starting in FROZEN Mode")
 else:
     print("Starting in NORMAL Mode")

 app = Flask(__name__)

 print("Instance Path   = {}".format(app.instance_path))
 print("Root Path       = {}".format(app.root_path))
 print("Templates Path  = {}".format(app.template_folder))
 print("Static Path     = {}".format(app.static_folder))
 print("Static URL Path = {}".format(app._static_url_path))
```

When running from IDE (VSCode), I get this:

```
Starting in NORMAL Mode
Instance Path   = h:\MyProject\Alfa1D\instance
Root Path       = h:\MyProject\Alfa1D\serversystem
Templates Path  = templates
Static Path     = h:\MyProject\Alfa1D\serversystem\static
Static URL Path = None
```

When running from exe file, this is the output:

```
Starting in FROZEN Mode
Instance Path   = C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI144962\var\serversystem-instance
Root Path       = C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI144962\serversystem
Templates Path  = templates
Static Path     = C:\Users\GP\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI144962\serversystem\static
Static URL Path = None
```

As I haven´t used the `template_folder=template_folder, static_folder=static_folder` options when creating the Flask app, the template and static files do not get packed so they don´t go to the temp MEI folder.

Is it possible to pack the EXE file and, when running it from where run.py is, make it use the template & static files from the fixed folders and not the temp one?

I use Python 3.10 and PyInstaller 4.7, on Windows 10.

Comment: I think it is possible tho, but you can use `--add-data` to manually bundle files too. (those files will be packed into the temp one)

Comment: @gfdsweds -- that´s exactly what I don´t want to do: pack the files into a temp directory.  I need them to be in the same location they are when I run the app from the IDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the following approach worked out well with the `--onefile` PyInstaller switch:

```
templatesDir = os.getcwd() + '/serversystem/templates'
staticDir = os.getcwd() + '/serversystem/static'

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=templatesDir, static_folder=staticDir)
```

As I´m running my main script from a folder that has a "serversystem" folder, where "templates" and "static" in turn are located, that´s my way to get it. If you have templates and static in direct folders, you should use `os.getcwd() + '/templates'` and the same for `'/static'`.

This worked great in both normal (Python interpreter) and frozen (Pyinstaller packaged) modes.

This reference helped a lot, specially the little sample script at the end:

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html